# Compare two arrays and return the corresponding value

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays of objects:

```js
const a = [
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jill',
    id: '25'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    id: '288'
  }
]
const b = [
  {
    title: 'alfa',
    a_id: '2'
  },
  {
    title: 'beta',
    a_id: '25'
  }
]


const test = b.map(i => {
  a.filter(u => {
    console.log(u.id === i.a_id)
    return Object.values(u).includes(i)
  })
})

console.log(test)
```

I have to loop trough `b`, and to check if the `a_id` corresponds with id from `a`, to return the name  from `a` that check the condition `a_id ==id`. How to do this?

at the final i have to get 2 names: Jill and Jack

Comment: what have you tried so far ? please post the code

Comment: @Code Maniac, i posted

Comment: If you're unsure whether all `b` elements have a corresponding `a` element: https://jsfiddle.net/p02jg5yb/

Comment: @Code Maniac, did you downvot the question?

Comment: @AskMen initially when there was no code posted i did, but when you updated your code I revoked my down vote. And changed it to upvote

Answer (score 2):

May not be the most optimal solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/5tzqj6ek/

```js
const a = [
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jill',
    id: '25'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    id: '288'
  }
]
const b = [
  {
    title: 'alfa',
    a_id: '2'
  },
  {
    title: 'beta',
    a_id: '25'
  }
]

var matchname = [];
b.forEach(objb => {
  a.forEach(obja => {
    if (objb.a_id === obja.id) {
      matchname.push(obja.name);
    }
  })
})
console.log(matchname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that :

```js
const a = [{
    name: 'Jack',
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jill',
    id: '25'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    id: '288'
  }
]
const b = [{
    title: 'alfa',
    a_id: '2'
  },
  {
    title: 'beta',
    a_id: '25'
  }
]

const test = b.map(i => {
  a.map(j => {
    console.log(j.id === i.a_id ? `${j.id} equals ${i.a_id}` : `not equals`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` and `find`

```js
const a = [{name: 'Jack',id: '2'},{name: 'Jill',id: '25'},{name: 'Bill',id: '288'}]
const b = [{title: 'alfa',a_id: '2'},{title: 'beta',a_id: '25'}]

b.forEach(i => {
  let found = a.find(u => u.id === i.a_id)
  if (found) {
    console.log(found.name)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `id`s are unique in your `a` object, you can make a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from these ids as keys which points to their name value. Then you can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `b` array to get the value from each `a_id` by looking it up in the `Map` using `.get()`:

```js
const a = [{ name: 'Jack', id: '2' }, { name: 'Jill', id: '25' }, { name: 'Bill', id: '288' } ]; 
const b = [{ title: 'alfa', a_id: '2' }, { title: 'beta', a_id: '25' } ];

const idMap = new Map(a.map(({name, id}) => [id, name]));
const res = b.map(({a_id}) => idMap.get(a_id));
console.log(res);
```

If your ids aren't unique, then you can use `.reduce()` to map to a `Map` of `id: array` pairs, where the `array` portion is the names for each id. Then you can use `.flatMap()` on the array to map each array to one larger array:

```js
const a = [{ name: 'Jack', id: '2' }, { name: 'Jill', id: '25' }, { name: 'Bill', id: '288' } ]; 
const b = [{ title: 'alfa', a_id: '2' }, { title: 'beta', a_id: '25' } ];

const idMap = a.reduce((map, {id, name}) => map.set(id, (map.get(id) || []).concat(name)), new Map);
const res = b.flatMap(({a_id}) => idMap.get(a_id));
console.log(res);
```